# ServiceStack AppHost().Init() throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, servicestack

my problem is that `AppHost().Init()` throws `System.ArgumentException` with `Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'`. Stack trace says

```
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters)
```

Some details about code: My current version ServiceStack is 4.0.52. I never reinstall or upgrade ServiceStack. I already have request DTO's which returns `int` in application and they worked fine couple days ago. I don't know what I did earlier that makes this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return Type for ServiceStack Services needs to be a reference type, ideally a Response DTO but can also be raw data type like a `string` and `byte[]`.

Comment: But as I said, my services contains methdos that returns value types e.g. bool or int and couple days ago works without error.

Comment: @Sidron obviously something has changed, either way the point remains you should never return value types, return it as a .ToString() if you need to.

Comment: Ok, one thing change. In my Exception Options I have checked `System.ArgumentException` to throw instanly and brake debug. When I uncheck this all works fine, but if response DTO's must return reference type, there is a reason why my services works and returns excatly what I want? Of course that methods with return value type.

Comment: @Sidron Your Services should return a Reference Type, Your Response DTOs can return what you like as the Response is itself a Reference Type. Returning Value Types was never supported and will fail in some features as you’ve noticed, don’t return them.